# creating a loop to go through different datasets with the same variable names to change values

Tags: python, loops

I have 4 datasets named cluster_1, cluster_2, cluster_3, cluster_4. I want to loop through all 4 and change the values of the variables to be binary, so if they are greater than or equal to 1 then it is just set to 1 and if it is 0 it is set to 0. All datasets have the same variable names.

i keep getting the error 'float' object is not iterable when running the code. 
binary is a list of the variable names and clusti is a list of the datasets.

````
    for i in binary:
        print(dataset[i])
        dataset[i] = dataset[i].apply(lambda x: [y if y== 0 else 1 for y in x]) ```
````

Comment: what is the output if dataset[i]?

Comment: What is the type of a "dataset"? There's no such thing in built in to Python. If you're using some framework, please tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try a using a comprehension to do this.

Given your code above, there are two distinct cases for the structure of `dataset`:

1. It's a list of lists, e.g.:

   dataset = [
       [0,1,2,3], 
       [1,2,3,4], 
       [0,0,2,1], 
       [1,0,1,0]
   ]
2. It's a keyed dict of lists, e.g.:

   dataset = {
       'cluster_1': [0,1,2,3],
       'cluster_2': [1,2,3,4],
       'cluster_3': [0,0,2,1],
       'cluster_4': [1,0,1,0]
   }

**CASE 1:** If your dataset is a list of lists, you can do this with a list comprehension:

```
dataset = [[int(y != 0) for y in x] for x in dataset]
```

What this does is create a list of lists:

1. The outer list comprehension `[█ for x in dataset]` evaluates as a comprehension  each list `x` in `dataset`,
2. The inner list comprehension `[█ for y in x]` evaluates each value `y` in the list `x`.
3. The expression `int(y != 0)` is a simplification of the ternary expression `y if y== 0 else 1`, because ternaries are clunky in Python. `y !=0` will result in a Boolean `False` if y == 0, else `True`.  Casting that to an `int()` will produce the same output as your ternary logic did (`0` if y is `0`, or `1` in all other cases).

Full example:

```
dataset = [
    [0,1,2,3], 
    [1,2,3,4], 
    [0,0,2,1], 
    [1,0,1,0]
]
dataset = [[int(y != 0) for y in x] for x in dataset]
print(dataset)
```

Yields:

> [[0, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1]]

**CASE 2:** If `dataset` is a dict, you can use a dict comprehension:

```
dataset = {key: [int(y != 0) for y in val] for key, val in dataset.items()}
```

Full example:

```
dataset = {
    'cluster_1': [0,1,2,3],
    'cluster_2': [1,2,3,4],
    'cluster_3': [0,0,2,1],
    'cluster_4': [1,0,1,0]
}
dataset = {key: [int(y != 0) for y in val] for key, val in dataset.items()}
print(dataset)
```

Yields:

> {'cluster_1': [0, 1, 1, 1], 'cluster_2': [1, 1, 1, 1], 'cluster_3': [0, 0, 1, 1], 'cluster_4': [1, 0, 1, 0]}

Comment: Probably should explain what `int(y != 0)` does because it isn't obvious.

Comment: The explanation of `int(y != 0)` is an improvement, but — sorry to be so pedantic — the formatting of some of the code snippets is missing and I'm not sure what to make of those `█` characters.

Comment: @martineau the block character is representing other code excluded from the portion being explained.